# Float matrix passed as a parameter to a function gives garbage values

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, floating-point, parameter-passing

I want to pass a `float` matrix to another function from the main function, the code being as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
 
// n must be passed before the 2D array
void print(int m, int n, float arr[][n])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
}
 
int main()
{
    float arr[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    int m = 3, n = 3;
    print(m, n, arr);
}
```

This gives the output: 3 -1742458874 -1742458874 -1742458874 -1742458874 -1742458874 -1742458874 -1742458874 -1742458874

I tried this by replacing `float` with `int` for the type of the array and it works perfectly fine. I expected it would work the same way with float, outputting "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" but instead it outputs garbage values.

Comment: A good compiler, with warnings enabled, makes it much easier to learn C.  My compiler immediately warned me `warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'float'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%d` is the wrong format for `float`s. Using `%f` should solve the issue, and you should see the expected results. If you want to print only the "whole" part of the float, you can specify the precision too:

```c
printf("%.0f ", arr[i][j]);
```